# Tensorflow's convert_image_dtype breaks image

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm converting a .png image to float32 the following way and I'm obtaining a broken image as shown below. If I remove the `tf.image.convert_image_dtype` call, everything goes well.

```
image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
```

I've also tried different images with different formats like .bmp and .jpg but same thing happens. The code I use to visualize the image generated the above way is just:

```
a = a.numpy()
a = Image.fromarray(a, 'RGB')
```

As I've said, if I just remove the `tf.image.convert_image_dtype` call everything goes well.

Here are the download links of both images (I have less than 10 reputation here so I can't upload photos yet).

[original_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGCfp.jpg)
[obtained_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud9fb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it back to integer like this

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = tf.io.read_file("C:\\<your file>.png")
image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)

a = image.numpy()
a = (a * 255 / np.max(a)).astype('uint8')
a = Image.fromarray(a, 'RGB')
a.show()
```

Comment: You're right. Thanks so much. Problem was on displaying the image. I got confused. Thanks again!